# Need help with a loop that gobbles up RAM

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsstring

I'm trying to get this loop to free all of the memory it uses, but it still gobbles up RAM pretty quickly. Hopefully someone can tell me how I can get the strings deallocating as they should. Basically, the loop writes doubles to a text file, and sometimes it has to write several megabytes of them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_samples; i++)
{
    if (print_str == nil)
    {
        print_str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    NSString* add_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\n%0.06f", number_of_seconds/number_of_samples*i];
    [print_str appendString:add_str];
    [add_str release];

    for (int g = 0; g < number_of_channels; g++)
    {
        add_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\t%f", data_buffer[g + i*number_of_channels]];
        [print_str appendString:add_str];
        [add_str release];
    }

    if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
    {
        fprintf(c_file_handle, "%s", [print_str UTF8String]);
        [print_str release];
        print_str = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Allocating new NSStrings is just the most recent thing I've tried.

Comment: Have you tried opening instruments to see where the memory is actually running away from you? Maybe allocations might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do with the string is not using the **print_str** cause it still holds all the strings and occupies memory. Use **"a"** option in **fopen** to append data to the file and append the formatted string **add_str** to the file instead of adding it to the memory buffer.

Comment: This led me to a solution. It wasn't the NSStrings taking up space, it was the file buffer. Now I'm periodically fclosing and then fopening the file, and that's keeping memory usage down :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're basically using that one string as a temporary buffer, how about allocating it once, and initWithFormatting it as often as you want?  Then release it when you're done with the loop.

```
NSString * add_str = [NSString alloc];

loop... {
    NSString* add_str = [ add_str initWithFormat:@"\n%0.06f", number_of_seconds/number_of_samples*i];
    [print_str appendString:add_str];
}
// end of loop

[add_str release];
```

Comment: I wouldn't try to initialize a single object more than once. That's definitely not an expected operation. Also, with a class cluster like NSString, you can never be sure that the initializer won't release the allocated object and give you back a different object.

Comment: The idea is not bad though. Instead of initializing it again, it can be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating strings and using `fprintf`, you might try using `NSOutputStream`. Your code might look something like this:

```
NSOutputStream *os = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"/path/to/file.ext"
                                                       append:YES];
[os open];
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_samples; i++) {
    // create a buffer to store the data to write
    [os write:buffer maxLength:bufferLength];
    // release the buffer
}
[os close];
```

This is a rough sketch - see the documentation for [NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003743) and [NSOutputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOutputStream) for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use `[print_str appendFormat:]` instead of allocating and releasing a new string each time.
2. When running in tight loops sometimes you need to create an [`NSAutoRelease`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) pool and periodically drain it and create a new one but I do not see you using any autoreleased objects.
3. Are you able to `free` the `data_buffer` as you go or do you use it again later? `free(data_buffer[g + i*number_of_channels]);`

Comment: (1) might help performance, but shouldn't change memory use. (2) won't help because there's nothing being added to the autorelease pool in the first place.

Comment: These are merely suggestions and I am aware that 2) does not use explicitly use any autoreleased objects but you never know what methods are used internally